# How should a JSON response be formatted?

Tags: json, rest

I have a REST service that returns a list of objects. Each object contains `objectcode` and `objectname`.

This is my first time building a REST service, so I'm not sure how to format the response.

Should it be:

```
{
    "objects": {
        "count": 2,
        "object": [
            {
                "objectcode": "1",
                "objectname": "foo"
            },
            {
                "objectcode": "2",
                "objectname": "bar"
            },
            ...more objects
        ]
    }
}
```

OR

```
 [
    {
        "objectcode": "1",
        "objectname": "foo"
    },
    {
        "objectcode": "2",
        "objectname": "bar"
    },
    ...more objects
]
```

I realize this might be a little subjective, but which would be easier to consume? I would also need to support XML formatted response later.

Comment: BTW, now I'm creating an app and the web service returns a response like the second one (an array in the root). The problem is that I cannot manage this situation with RestKit. Is there any limitation I don't know? how do you create the response descriptors when the response is an array? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same to consume, as a library handles both just fine. The first one has an advantage over the second though: You will be able to expand the response to include other information additional to the objects (for example, categories) without breaking existing code.

Something like

```
{
    "objects": {
        "count": 2,
        "object": [
            {
                "objectcode": "1",
                "objectname": "foo"
            },
            {
                "objectcode": "2",
                "objectname": "bar"
            },
            ...more objects
        ]
    }

 "categories": {
  "count": 2,
  "category" : [
     { "name": "some category"}
  ]
  }
}
```

Additionally, the json shouldn't be formatted in any way, so remove whitespace, linebreaks etc. Also, the count isn't really necessary, as it will be saved while parsing the objects themselves.

Comment: You make some good points I didn't think of. Its definitely great to have the response expandible without breaking existing code, and count does seem redundant if the response has to be parsed anyways.

Comment: This is the way Facebook returns all their JSON requests, so I would consider that a plus for this format. It gives you a lot of flexibility while maintaining consistency in your responses.

Comment: Yep, I had the same experience (supporting multiple iPhone app versions with different responses). If I had followed the second approach, I would've broken previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

I often see the first one. Sometimes it's easier to manipulate data to have meta-data. For exemple google API use first one : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

Comment: The google response has a field `"Status" : "Ok"`. Shouldn't that be conveyed via the header?

Comment: The field 'status' indicate if the server return data. It's to differentiate 'error status' on the url or parameters, and 'no data status'. If it was conveyed in the header, developer can make the difference.

Comment: Good answer for mentioning the meta-data usage. And also thanks for providing a real world example. As to @xbonez 's question about "status", that is a (debatable?) philosophy from JSend http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend

Answer (score 1):

It's not only the question of personal preference; it's also the question fo your requirements. For example, if I was in the same situation and I did need object count on client side then I'd go with first approach otherwise I will choose the second one.

Also please note that "classic" REST server mostly will work a bit different way. If some REST function is to return a list of objects then it should return only a list of **URLs** to those objects. The URLs should be pointing to details endpoints - so by querying each endpoint you may get details on specific single object.

Answer (score -1):

As a client I would prefer the second format. If the first format only includes the number of "objects", this is redundant information.